# What is the difference between removeLast() and popLast() methods of Array in Swift?

Tags: arrays, swift

What is the difference between removeLast() and popLast() methods of Array in Swift? They are doing the same thing, removing and returning the last element of the array. Can someone tell me when to use what?

Answer (score 41, accepted):

Those two methods are from `AnyRandomAccessCollection` which Array conforms to.

`popLast` returns `nil` if the collection is empty.

`removeLast` crashes if the collection is empty. It also has a discardable result.

Comment: Not quite – `Array` can't conform to `AnyRandomAccessCollection`, as that's a type-erased wrapper, not a protocol. `removeLast` is a default implementation for a [`RangeReplaceableCollection` when it's also a `BidirectionalCollection`](https://github.com/apple/swift/blob/master/stdlib/public/core/RangeReplaceableCollection.swift.gyb#L983) (which an `Array` is) and `popLast` is [defined by `Array` directly](https://github.com/apple/swift/blob/master/stdlib/public/core/Arrays.swift.gyb#L2237).

Comment: @rmaddy the quick documentation in xcode is identical for both methods, and these days Stack Overflow is a lot of developers' first stop for quick questions like this, with R'ing TFM often being less efficient. I for one am glad this question and answer are here, thank you :)

Comment: The quick documentation isn't identical for both methods (at least not now). It indicates the difference in behavior for empty collections.

Answer (score 5):

popLast() returns an optional, so it can be nil;
removeLast() returns the last element, not optional, so it will crash if the array is empty.

You need to use @discardableResult for popLast() if you don't use the returned element, while removeLast() doesn't need to.